# Common header file with navbar change color

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I have a header.php file included in index.php and on other pages of my website. In my header tab I have a navbar and I want to make each tab active according to the respective page. Ex(About page - about tab color should change, for contact - contact tab shoud change color)

Comment: Great -- what is your question? Where is your code?

Comment: Please reread [ask] and provide a [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend include on top (before loading header.php) name of the file.
Then in header you can make simple statement, f.ex.

$page_title = 'Home Page';

And then in header.php, in you nav menu:

```
<a href='#' class='someClass <?php echo $page_title === 'Home Page' ? 'active' : ''; ?>"> Home Page </a>
```

And 'active' class will be responsible for styles for current page.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this entirely within CSS. Given the following header HTML:

```
<nav class="header">
  <ul>
    <li class="home"><a href="/home.php">Home</a></li>
    <li class="about"><a href="/about.php">About</a></li>
    <li class="contact"><a href="/contact.php">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

You would then add the classes "home", "about", and "contact" to the `<body>` tag of your Home, About, and Contact pages, respectively. Then, you create the following CSS:

```
body.home nav li.home,
body.about nav li.about,
body.contact nav li.contact {
  background-color: red; /* or however you want to style the active tab */
}
```